# ios - I want to add View with CellFrame

Tags: ios, addsubview, uitableview

I add view in TableViewCell like this.

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  UITableViewCell * cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]init];
  UIView * view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:cell.frame];
  view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
  [cell addSubview: view];

}
```

I would like to add View with Cell Frame

but result is
[image]
How do I do?

Comment: have you test my code?

Answer (score 0):

If you create separate class and add view on that then it will show on full cell, but if you don't want to create separate class for cell then use following code.
in that I have set view width as same as table view width

```
 UITableViewCell * cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]init];
        UIView * view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.tableView.frame.size.height, cell.frame.size.height)];
        view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
        cell.backgroundColor =[UIColor purpleColor];
        [cell addSubview: view];
```

I hope it will helps you!